# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.?

Tags: asp.net, email, authentication, smtp

I have find many answers on this problem but still no solution to my problem. I am using this code to send Account Activation mail to the user. But i get this error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
        string body = "Hello " + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + ",";
body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate    your   account";
        body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("CS.aspx", "CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "<password>");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        //var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        //{
        //    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
        //    EnableSsl = true
        //};
        //client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to use your own credentials, you need to set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is like water, code executes from top-to-bottom. You're passing the credentials, but at the same time setting the UseDefaultCredentials to true. Which causes this problem. Most of the servers require authentication, such as EnableSsl and credentials (username/password combination) in order to send the emails from their server.

So, the solution would be to remove this following line,

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Then the code would execute and the email would be sent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually i just entered the valid gmail username and password and it worked for me =)